# An inequality from Stirling formula.

Tags: calculus

In [https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~tijdeman/hantijd4.pdf](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Etijdeman/hantijd4.pdf)
the authors assert (page 12 line 3) that
$$qa^nc^na_{2n}\frac{n!(2n-1)!}{(3n)!}+o(n^{-n/8})>\frac1{7^n}$$
for $n$ large enough, where $q,a,c$ are positive reals and $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of positive reals such that $a_n=o(n^{-n/7})$ [edit: **in fact it is $a_n=o(n^{n/7})$]**.
I must be dumb, but I did not manage to prove it. Any answer would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns out that $\dfrac{n!(2n-1)!}{(3n)!}$ is roughly $(\frac4{27})^n$ when $n$ is large, for your information. But now with the $a_{2n}$ term added, this inequality seems false.

Comment: Sorry for the edit. You were very fast  to answer !!

Comment: The left-hand side is $$
o(1)n^{ - 2n/7 - 1/2} \left( {\frac{{4^{6/7} ac}}{{27}}} \right)^n  + o(n^{ - n/8} ).
$$ This is always smaller than the right-hand side if $n$ is large enough. I think the paper uses $a_n=o(n^{n/7})$ (and not $a_n=o(n^{-n/7})$). In that case, the statement is correct.

Comment: Ah, right, it is $o(n^{n/7})$

Comment: My last statement is not correct since $a_n$ can for example be $n^{-n}$, since certainly $n^{-n}=o(n^{n/7})$. We need an $\Omega$ (or $\omega$) expression for $a_n$ to be sure.